# How can I get my asp.net mvc5 application to change my sql table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

So I have an MVC5 ASP.NET application I'm building on Visual Studios 2017 and I have a stored procedure that is properly pulling and displaying data. However, I want the user to be able to click create, edit, or delete (I want a soft delete, but I can handle that later) and for that change to then be reflected and saved in the actual SQL table that currently only has one entry. I've used entity frameworks and was advised that I need to have a manner of identifying each row. So I tried to create an ID property so each row could be uniquely identified. The field that was initially the primary key is incorrect. Now here's where the problem lies. I've tried rolling back my old migration and running a new one but to no avail. Ive tried all the entity frameworks manipulation that I can think of but I'm stuck. Any help would be great.

Here's the code for my edit, if someone can just get this working for me I can do the rest. This was almost all automatically generated.

```
    // GET: Exclusions/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? ID)
    {
        if (ID == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Exclusion exclusion = db.Exclusions.Find(ID);
        if (exclusion == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(exclusion);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PolicyNo,PolicyMod,InsuredName,ClientID")] Exclusion exclusion)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(exclusion).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(exclusion);
    }
```

Here is the new migration I attempted to run and even though it succeeded made no difference

```
public partial class Migration1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Exclusion1", 
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    PolicyNo = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PolicyMod = c.String(),
                    InsuredName = c.String(),
                    ClientID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Exclusion1");
    }
}
```

If anymore information is needed I'll gladly offer it, just ask. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's a little more info:
The application runs but when I click on edit next to the entry it takes me to HTTP Error 400.0 page. When I click on edit the url becomes XXXX/Exclusions/124369622 which is the value of the old primary key instead of 1 which should be the new one. But if I manually type 1 at the end of the URL I still get nowhere. I just want to be able to edit a field and have that reflect in my SQL table that is created by a stored procedure

Comment: Specifically, what is the issue you're running into?

Comment: The application runs but when I click on edit next to the entry it takes me to HTTP Error 400.0 page. When I click on edit the url becomes XXXX/Exclusions/124369622 which is the value of the old primary key instead of 1 which should be the new one. But if I manually type 1 at the end of the URL I still get nowhere. I just want to be able to edit a field and have that reflect in my SQL table that is created by a stored procedure.

Comment: @RoshaanKhan it may automatically infer the Edit, not sure, but should it be XXXX/Exclusions/Edit/{Id} that should be generated? Seems it is missing the /Edit.

Comment: @Robert I completed my MVC application. The problem is now with my web forms version. You should be able to see the question on my profile. Thanks!